# pendig bootstrap modal in click for load remote data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for load dynamic data from remote file into bootstrap using jquery ajax :

JS:

```
$(function(){

   $('.push').click(function(){
      var essay_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'your_url.php', // in here you should put your query 
        data :  'post_id='+ essay_id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                     // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
       success : function(r)
           {
              // now you can show output in your modal 
              $('#mymodal').show();  // put your modal id 
             $('.something').show().html(r);
           }
    });
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="1" class="push">click</a> 

<div class="modal-body">  
   <div class="something" style="display:none;">
     // here you can show your output dynamically 
   </div>
</div>
```

this worked for me But modal box not show until/pending data loaded. I need to load modal box after click and then load data.

how do fix this?!

Comment: put $('#mymodal').show(); into first line of click handler method before ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You could make the ajax call outside your click event on load and show hide on click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var essay_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
var results;

$.ajax({ 
      type : 'post', 
      url :  'your_url.php',
      async: false
      'post_id='+ essay_id, 
      success : function(r) { 
          results = r;
      } 
 });

$(' your_element').click(function() {
      if (results) {
          $('#mymodal').show(); 
          $('.something').show().html(results); 
      } 
 });
 });
```

Using **async:false** will force it to finish your request before continuing the script. Hope this helps.